# How to create multiple XML files if single XML file matches the requirements?

Tags: xml, go, split

Below is my client code which stream all the customer url's from `golang grpc` server and it works fine. It takes `Request` input parameter and streams `customer url's` basis on a particular `clientId`.  In my below  code, I am streaming all customer url's for `ClientId 12345` and it works fine.

I am also creating an XML file with all the URL's in it for particular `clientId` as shown below. For example: Below will create `12345_abc.xml` XML file with all the URL's in them in particular format.

```
func main() {
    // this "clientId" will be configurable in future
    clientId := 12345
    timeout := time.Duration(1000) * time.Millisecond
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, "localhost:50005", grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("can not connect with server %v", err)
    }

    // create stream
    client := pb.NewCustomerServiceClient(conn)
    req := &pb.Request{ClientId: clientId}
    stream, err := client.FetchResponse(context.Background(), req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("open stream error %v", err)
    }
    // create new object to populate all URL data in memory
    urlHolder := NewClient()
    t := time.Unix(0, 0).UTC()
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            resp, err := stream.Recv()
            if err == io.EOF {
                done <- true
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("can not receive %v", err)
            }
            log.Printf("Resp received: %s", resp.GetCustomerUrl())
            // populate URL object with all the required field in it
            urlHolder.Add(&URL{
               Loc:        resp.GetCustomerUrl(),
               LastMod:    &t,
               ChangeFreq: Daily,
               Priority:   10.2,
            })
        }
    }()

    <-done
    log.Printf("finished")
    // create an XML file with all the URL's in it and then save it on disk
    // for particular clientId. This will create "12345_abc.xml"
    file, _ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%d_abc.xml", clientId))
    urlHolder.WriteTo(file)
}
```

Here is my `urlholder.go` file:

```
type URL struct {
    Loc        string     `xml:"loc"`
    LastMod    *time.Time `xml:"lastmod"`
    ChangeFreq ChangeFreq `xml:"changefreq"`
    Priority   float32    `xml:"priority"`
}

type UrlMap struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"urlset"`
    Xmlns   string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    URLs    []*URL   `xml:"url"`
    Minify  bool     `xml:"-"`
}

func NewClient() *UrlMap {
    return &UrlMap{
        Xmlns: "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
        URLs:  make([]*URL, 0),
    }
}

func (s *UrlMap) Add(u *URL) {
    s.URLs = append(s.URLs, u)
}

// WriteTo writes XML encoded urlMap to given io.Writer.
func (s *UrlMap) WriteTo(w io.Writer) (n int64, err error) {
    cw := NewCounterWriter(w)
    _, err = cw.Write([]byte(xml.Header))
    if err != nil {
      return cw.Count(), err
    }
    en := xml.NewEncoder(cw)
    if !s.Minify {
      en.Indent("", "  ")
    }
    err = en.Encode(s)
    cw.Write([]byte{'\n'})
    return cw.Count(), err
}
```

Here is my `CounterWriter` class -

```
// CounterWriter implements io.Writer. Count of bytes written is tracked.
type CounterWriter struct {
    writer io.Writer
    count  int64
}

var _ io.Writer = (*CounterWriter)(nil)

// NewCounterWriter wraps io.Writer and returns CounterWriter.
func NewCounterWriter(w io.Writer) (cw *CounterWriter) {
    return &CounterWriter{
        writer: w,
    }
}

// Write calls Write on the wrapped io.Writer and adds the number of bytes
// written to the counter.
func (cw *CounterWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = cw.writer.Write(p)
    cw.count = cw.count + int64(n)
    return n, err
}

// Count returns the number of bytes written to the Writer.
func (cw *CounterWriter) Count() (n int64) {
    return cw.count
}
```

**Problem Statement**

Above code works fine but I need to split an `XML` file into multiple `XML` files for same `clientId` if it matches below requirements:

- A single `XML` file should not be more than `50MB` max. It can be approximate, doesn't have to be accurate.
- A single `XML` file should not have more than `50K` URL's max.

I know it's weird that 50k URL limit will be reached sooner than 50MB limit but this is what I got the requirement. Now basis on above logic, I need to make multiple XML files for particular `clientId`. All those multiple files can be like this `12345_abc_1.xml`, `12345_abc_2.xml` or any other better naming format. I am kinda confuse on how should I proceed to do this.

I can add logic for `50K` url by using for loop but confuse on the size logic and also I want to make this generic for each `clientId` so I am having difficulties doing this.

Comment: It looks like you're storing just the URLs and not the contents? Am I missing something? 

In that case, wouldn't you reach your 50k URL limit way before your file size gets to 50 MB?

Comment: Yes I am not storing the content just URL's pretty much. And that is correct it can reach 50k URL limit much before than 50MB but that is the requirement I got so I need to figure out a way to do this both while generating the XML file. @JohnSPerayil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `WriteTo` function, you should be calling something like `w.Write(myBytes)`.

The size of `myBytes` inside that function is the size that you are looking for. You can get it using `len(myBytes)` or with the first return of `w.Write(myBytes)`. This is important because there is no way of "estimating" the size that a file would have, other than directly counting the information that you will write.

You are converting `UrlMap` into bytes somewhere inside your `WriteTo` function. That means you can do the same with any `URL` variable.

The way that I would solve this problem is to have a `sizeCounter` and add the number of bytes that would be stored everytime I create a new `URL` variable inside the `for {` loop. In the same place I would also count the number of `URL`s created. With both counters then the rest is easy.

I would add the transformation from `URL` to `bytes` inside the `.Add` function and return it so that everything is easier to understand. You are going to have to move some variables into the go routine.

```golang
func (s *UrlMap) Add(u *URL) (int) { // Modify this function to count the size and return it
    s.URLs = append(s.URLs, u)

    var urlBytes []byte
    var err error

    urlBytes, err = xml.Marshal(u) // Transform to bytes using xml.Marshal or xml.MarshalIndent
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // or return the error if you want
    }

    return len(urlBytes)
}
```

```golang
    t := time.Unix(0, 0).UTC()
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        // create new object to populate all URL data in memory
        urlHolder := NewClient()
        urlCounter := 0
        byteCounter := 0
        fileCounter := 0

        for {
            resp, err := stream.Recv()
            if err == io.EOF {
                done <- true
                file, _ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%d_abc_%d.xml", clientId, fileCounter))
                urlHolder.WriteTo(file)
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("can not receive %v", err)
            }
            log.Printf("Resp received: %s", resp.GetCustomerUrl())
            // I add the bytes of the URL here as a return
            urlBytes := urlHolder.Add(&URL{
               Loc:        resp.GetCustomerUrl(),
               LastMod:    &t,
               ChangeFreq: Daily,
               Priority:   10.2,
            })
            byteCounter += urlBytes
            urlCounter += 1
            if byteCounter > 49000000 || urlCounter >= 50000 { 
                file, _ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%d_abc_%d.xml", clientId, fileCounter))
                urlHolder.WriteTo(file)
                urlHolder = NewClient() // create a new object for next loop
                fileCounter += 1 // prepare fileCounter for next loop
                byteCounter = 0 // restart count variables
                urlCounter = 0
            }
        }
    }()

    <-done
    log.Printf("finished")
    // No longer write the files here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I updated my question to add my full `WriteTo` method and how it uses my `counterwriter.go` class as well. My `WriteTo` method returns the byte as well. Can you take a look at my updated code and see if anything can be improved now? Do we still need to do what you are doing in `Add` method to return bytes now? Also you mentioned I need to move some variables to go routine? Can you provide an example how that will look like with my updated code if possible. I am pretty new to golang so still trying to understand on how should I design the code efficiently.

Comment: The variables that I meant to move into the goroutine are basically the new counters, the `urlHolder` and the `file`, as all of them all will need to change without interrupting the loop.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how that will look like as I am currently confuse on this. Also with my updated code, do you think any changes is needed in your suggestion or I can still use as it is? I mean do we need to return bytes from `Add` method now with my updated code?

Comment: It should work as it is now. Modifying `Add` or not is up to you. I placed it there to have less code changes. You could create a function that just gets the number of bytes from the `URL` struct using the given `xml.Marshal` function. I don't see where the `WriteTo` function writes all the `s.URLs` into the file, and maybe you should change `cw.Write([]byte{'\n'})` for that. But that is a different problem.

Comment: yeah I missed that writing part so I will look at `cw.Write([]byte{'\n'})` later on but you think there is nothing needed to be changed in `WriteTo` function w.r.t your suggestion related to multiple xml file generation right?

Comment: Try changing `cw.Write([]byte{'\n'})` to these two lines: `urlMapBytes, _ := xml.Mashal(s)` and then `cw.Write(urlMapBytes)` to get it working. That is in the `WriteTo` function. I don't think you would need many more changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242086/discussion-between-andyp-and-emmanuelb).